# what are console symbols like $ and %

Tags: shell, terminal, console

I always see representations of console commands like this:

```
$ ...
$ ......
% ..
```

does the symbols **$** and **%** represents something specially/different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those symbols are (or have been ) the default shell prompt on various *nix systems. They're generically used to indicate the place of a shell prompt, preceding where you would type some command.

There's no difference in meaning between these, they just stem from different shells.

Comment: Not only that - people use different characters to show what kind of user you are logged in as. For example - normal users can have a $ prompt and root user # prompt. It is just a convention to get an idea of whether you are currently a normal user or a root user. Nothing prevents any user from using any such prompt character though.

Comment: @RaviH that's an excellent point, and one where the symbol can be expect to differentiate meaning.

Comment: any name or article about this convention?

Comment: @user3175226 no reference that I'm aware of. It's just a practice I've seen done for about 30 years (since I've been looking, but the shells are older!). Drawing on less clear recollection, I think "csh" based shells might have defaulted to % being their default prompt, while "sh" based shells (like the popular bash shell) defaulted to $. And as RaviH addresses, # is used to indicate a root shell (for both shell families).

Answer (score 1):

Most common shells have one of the following displays:

`user@hostname $`

`user@hostname %`

It's a convention, so when writing console commands, we use these symbols to represent "This is a new command."

Comment: I thought symbols represents each different language or program. thanks.